# Issue pushing to github because old commit is invalid, but newest commit is not (filesize issues)

Tags: git, github

So I had a file over 100mb, which GitHub doesn't like. So I split the file, and made a new commit. So now there are 2 commits ahead of remote. 1 with the >100mb, and 1 with 2 <100mb files. When I push, it get's upset because of the >100mb file, even though that doesn't exist in the newest version. How can I fix this? I don't particularly need the sepraation of commits, is there anyway I can turn the 2 commits into 1 commit (in reality it says 9 ahead of origin/master because of other work done since)?

```
$ git push origin develop 
Counting objects: 103, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (101/101), done.
Writing objects: 100% (103/103), 50.28 MiB | 3.42 MiB/s, done.
Total 103 (delta 72), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (72/72), completed with 27 local objects.
remote: warning: File lib/seeder/data/sessions_1.sql is 75.61 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File lib/seeder/data/sessions_2.sql is 90.60 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: a1f8d12ad4bb23a87c60a694b5a48a9e
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File lib/seeder/data/sessions.sql is 166.21 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/me/backend.git
 ! [remote rejected] develop -> develop (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/me/backend.git'
$ git status
On branch develop
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/develop' by 9 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Comment: i would think a step before, would git be the best version control for a 100mb file? in this case I would recommend SVN (assuming that is a binary not a code file, although git has the git lfs for it)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is a "history rewrite", which probably can be done as an interactive rebase.  The exact command depends on a few things.  If you are on a branch that's tracking a remote branch, and you don't have any branches and merges between what's on the origin and what you have locally, then

```
git rebase -i
```

may be sufficient to get the process started.  If this is the initial push, you might need to do something like

```
git rebase -i --root
```

It would be difficult to cover every possibility, so if it's not clear what command you need, you can either consult the rebase documentation (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) or possibly provide more information about the current state of your repo (or how you got to where you are).

This will bring up a text editor with a "todo" list, showing one commit per line.

Now the potential problem is, you mention there are something like 7 other commits.  If the commit that broke up the file is immediately after the commit that created it, it's no problem.  Just locate the line for the commit that breaks the file up, and change its first word from "pick" to "squash".  This will combine it with the prior commit (which created the file), effectively discarding the prior commit's `TREE`.

If they aren't "back to back", then you could reorder the commits. Move the line for the commit that breaks the file up so that it appears right after the commit that created the file, and then change it as above from "pick" to "squash".  This may or may not work cleanly.  (That is, there may be conflicts as the changes are replayed "out of order".)